# How to subset netcdf CRU V4.00 data in R using lat-lon?

Tags: r, netcdf, cdo-climate

I want to subset a region from cru global data. The "cmsaf" package , box_mergetime function can subset the CMIP5 and CORDEX .nc data but in CRU .nc data it gives following error.

```
>library(cmsaf)
>wd<-getwd()
>box_mergetime("tmp", wd, "cru_ts4.00.1901.1910", "output", 67,98,8,38)

get file information 
[1] "vobjtovarid4: error #F: I could not find the requsted var (or dimvar) in the file!"
[1] "var (or dimvar) name: longitude"
[1] "file name: C:/Users/Deepak/Documents/eg/ip/cru_ts4.00.1901.1910.tmp.nc"
Error in vobjtovarid4(nc, varid, verbose = verbose, allowdimvar = TRUE) : 
 Variable not found
```

[link of data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9ACBRSUXCjndlFMV05jLVNBbkk).

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this error message was a missing standard name of longitude and latitude in CRU NetCDF data. I fixed this issue and with cmsaf version 1.8.0 it should work now. The cmsaf package offers similar functions as cdo (e.g., sellonlatbox, timmean, fldmean are included).

Comment: It showing following error now                                  

Error in order(time_sorting) : object 'time_sorting' not found.

Comment: This error occurs in case you apply the box_mergetime function to only one file. This function was build to cut and merge multiple files. To cut a region from a single NetCDF file use the sellonlatbox function of the cmsaf package.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to do this from the command line with CDO before reading into R

Select a box:

```
cdo sellonlatbox,lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2 in.nc out.nc
```

Do a time mean:

```
cdo timmean in.nc out.nc
```

Do a space mean:

```
cdo fldmean in.nc out.nc
```

If you are using Ubuntu you can install cdo easily with

```
sudo apt-get install cdo
```

and under windows you can install it under CYGWIN. (update: rather than cygwin, these days far better to simply install linux subsystem under windows 10, very easy to do and then you have ubuntu straight out of the box)